# How do I set up ImageShiftGallery to work inside a draggable object?

Tags: javascript, slideshow, draggable

I’m trying to use BuzaMoto’s ImageShiftGallery (MudShiftContent would work as well. It was actually my first choice, but I found it even more complicated) to work with the template I have set up.

I’ve been banging my head against the wall for a while and I just can not make it work.

**Can somebody help me turn that static image into a slideshow with ImageShiftGallery?** (or MudShiftContent or any other javascript able to accomplish the same result…)

All I need is a manual slideshow inside the draggable panel (I’m using Walter Zorn’s Drag & Drop javascript) with a description and prev/next buttons at the bottom, like example #2 from ImageShiftGallery’s zip.

**Javascript is not my forte so any help will be highly appreciated.**

Here's the template I'm working with:

```
http://jmp.sh/xbYMuEv
```

Here is BuzaMoto’s ImageShiftGallery:

```
https://github.com/mud/imageshiftgallery/tree/master
```